# how to convert ASCII code to char in c++?

Tags: c++, encryption, char, ascii

In my class my teacher has gave me a homework about encrypt and decrypt password. In this homework, the algorithm is to find out how to decrypt to it's previous user has inputted.In fact, How to convert it from ASCII code back to char. Is there any way to do that? thanks.

This is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    //reverse
    cout << "Please input password: ";
    cin >> pwd;
    int size = pwd.length();
    const int maxSize = 100;
    char pwdReversed[maxSize];
    int pwdEncrypted[maxSize];
    int j = 0;
    cout << "Reversed Password: ";
    for(int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        cout << pwd[i];

        pwdReversed[j] = pwd[i];
        pwdEncrypted[j] = (int)pwd[i];
        j++;


    }
    cout<< endl;
    //Output
    cout << "Encrypted pwd: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < j; i++){
        cout << pwdEncrypted[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is for specific issues and errors, not "how do I do this" questions. If you have a specific question about some code, please reduce your question to that and show us what you have done to attempt a solution/what didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it to `char` (on the vast majority of architectures, the character set used is compatible with ASCII).

```
    cout << (char)pwdEncrypted[i];
```